# How to custom a listview in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to create a listbox in C# to view my contacts list.  Can anyone help me learn to create a custom listbox similar to http://mozillalinks.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/downloadtweaks1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your custom drawing logic inside DrawItem event. Sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx).